# start Ubuntu 18.04 an error : end kernel panic -not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b occurs by stack smashing detected

Tags: locale, downgrade

I downgraded my Ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04 today. After rebooting and logining the downgraded 18.04, I met an error as follows:

[image]

Then I ran the following commands in the terminal hoping to fix it.

```
sudo apt remove --purge locales
sudo apt install locales
```

Unfortunately, the second command failed with the error: `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`. Then I run any command, this error would occur.

So I shut down and restarted the computer by pressing down the power button. Finally, the 18.04 OS failed to start with the following errors.

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. As you probably feel, you screwed it up big time. You should ***never, ever*** remove the locales package. And you should really not try to "downgrade" either. You should have saved your `$HOME` somewhere and made a fresh install of 18.04 instead. So I guess you need to start it all over.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have reinstalled a ubuntu 20.04 in my computer. Fortunately, when I installed Ubuntu 18.10 earlier, I had a separate partition for the home, So my data does not lose. Well, what is the role of the 'locals'?

Comment: Well, you can run `apt show locales` to get a hint. It's built by the `glibc` source package, which is one of the core packages that simply must be there on a working system.